# Generic flash downloader

Tags: 12.04, downloads

There are several content downloaders like You_tube_downloader and many others. However i don't wnat something which is specific to one site or another. is there something like Real_player_for_windows which is capable of downoading_any flash content which it comes across any_website on the internet. I need something generic and which holds true for every website not just one or two

Comment: jdownloader is a really good all-round downloader

Comment: will it work on 90% of others' not just youtube ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable in using firefox addon, use `DownloadHelper`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, **FlareGet** would be an ideal choice for you. It is available for free in Ubuntu Software Center

> FlareGet is a full featured, multi-threaded and multi-segment download manager and accelerator

But the free version in Ubuntu software center does not support "Browser integration", you need to pay $10 to get browser integration plugin. I guess without browser integration, download manager won't make sense.

So here is the workaround to get Broeser integration for Firefox. I have tested it on Firefox 18 and it works like a charm.

> - Just go to Firefox > Tools > Add ons > Extensions.
> - Search for addon "**FlashGot**", install it and Restart the Firefox.
> - Go to Tools > Add ons > Extension > Preferences for FlashGot.
> - On General tab, choose FlareGet as download manager and check the check-box against "Show in Context Menu"
> - On FlashGot tab, choose FlareGet as download manager and check the check-box against "Show Toolbar button".
> - Now restart the Firefox. FlashGot will act as Firefox integration plugin for FlareGet.

Just right click any downloadable link and choose FlareGet.

> If you want you download video from YouTube just play the video, an icon will appear on right most side of the tile bar. Just click on that icon and FlareGet will capture and download the video.

I love Firefox so this is enough for me. Something similar can be worked out for Chrome.

Comment: Please avoid posting the same answer in more than one place. When tempted to do so, often the answer should be customized to account for what is different about the different questions (I recommend that here, as the questions, and thus the way this solution will be used, are substantially different), or (2) one question should be flagged for closure as a duplicate of another question. (You can flag posts once you gain [15 reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts) on the site.)